# Allows Tampermonkey in Safari to acces files on my computer

Tags: safari, greasemonkey, safari-extension, tampermonkey

How can I use `@require` using Tampermonkey in Safari?

If I use it, and point to the .js file on my file system, that javascript never gets executed. Presumably because I need to allow Tampermonkey to access files on my file system. How can I do that? I am looking for an option similar to this one in Chrome:

[image]

Comment: This question has been discussed in a [forum](https://forum.tampermonkey.net/viewtopic.php?t=316), but I haven't tried yet. Please add an answer to your own question when you have experienced how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, you can't.

To the best of my knowledge, Safari blocks every attempt of extension to access local files. The only place extensions have access is the `baseURI` of the extension and it's subfolders. I wrote my own extension and tried to change JS files in the baseURI folder manually, to see if the user script changes accordingly. It doesn't. Safari keeps a copy of it's current state and ignores any changes made to the baseURI, unless you click `reload` extension command.